Flutter never asks for any storage permission
So I was using the open_file library to open some pdf files. When I switched from cache storage to app's local document folder storage using getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(), the files were not opening. Using
var result = await OpenFile.open(filePath);
print(result.message);

return Permission denied: android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
My filePath is in the format /data/user/0/com.example.<app name>/app_flutter/New-Note-2024-09-19-00-02-48.pdf
It is a bit strange that I need permission to access my app's local storage
Nevertheless I included
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    
    <application
     ....
</manifest>

In my AndroidManifest.xml, and here is my flutter code for requesting permissions:
   Future<void> requestStoragePermission() async {
      if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
        // Permission granted
      } else {
          openAppSettings();
        // Handle permission denied
        print("Storage permission denied");
      }
    }

However it defaults automatically to "Permission denied" without me even doing anything.
And if I go to app settings, it shows "No permissions requested" and outputs No permissions found in manifest for: []15.
I even tried including READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on my manifest, still doesn't work.

What is the API level that your application compiles/targets?

@tomerpacific sorry for not including this earlier, it is set to the latest API level as I kept the values at the default flutter.targetSdkVersion.

Have you followed this?

I finally found my solution, the issue was using getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(), should've used getExternalStorageDirectory().
This should've occurred to me naturally as by using application's local documents directory to save files I was trying to access my App's local files from another external app when running Openfile.open(), which would have not worked. Just like how you can't browse an app's local directory from a File Manager (unless rooted).
